# NSLayoutConstraints issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've disabled autolayout from xib. But I'm facing this issue. Even I'm not adding any subview programmatically, and I'm having 3 element in this view:

**1. UIImageView 2. UIButton 3. UIButton.**

I'm suffering for the last 3 days but I'm not able to find out the error. So please any one help me. Your help will be appreciated.

```
NSLog(@"Constratins %@",[self.view constraints]);
Constratins (
)


View hierarchy unprepared for constraint.
    Constraint: <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x294d9de0 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x2d91c410.midY == UINavigationTransitionView:0xdd2aa40.midY>
    Container hierarchy: 
<UINavigationTransitionView: 0xdd2aa40; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xdd2aca0>>
   | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x2a72b4d0; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); layer = <CALayer: 0x2a72ab40>>
   |    | <UIView: 0x2d869b30; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2d8852e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x2d86b510>>
   |    |    | <MyImageView: 0x2d891040; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (0 0; 1024 748); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x2d8699f0>> - (null)
   |    |    | <UIButton: 0x2d88c460; frame = (968 14; 40 40); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x2d88c550>>
   |    |    | <UIButton: 0x2d88a220; frame = (963 9; 40 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x2d88a310>>
    View not found in container hierarchy: <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x2d91c410; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x2d91c490>>
    That view's superview: NO SUPERVIEW
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found the solution.  The reason is : not setting the frame of **UIViewControllerWrapperView**
So i've do this

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.tabBarController.view.superview.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```